# Generate all unique substrings for given string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given a string `s`, what is the fastest method to generate a set of all its unique substrings?

Example: for `str = "aba"` we would get `substrs={"a", "b", "ab", "ba", "aba"}`.

The naive algorithm would be to traverse the entire string generating substrings in length `1..n` in each iteration, yielding an `O(n^2)` upper bound.

Is a better bound possible?

*(this is technically homework, so pointers-only are welcome as well)*

Comment: @Yuval..Did you get the efficient algo? Please share it if you have. TIA.

Comment: I don't really remember what happened. But most likely I ended up implementing some sort of suffix tree. Don't have the code anymore, sorry.

Comment: The proposed algorithm does *not* run in O(n²) time!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As other posters have said, there are potentially O(n^2) substrings for a given string, so printing them out cannot be done faster than that. However there exists an efficient representation of the set that can be constructed in linear time: [the suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

Comment: This is O(n+L) where L is number of unique substrings, I believe. So it is optimal.

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to do this faster than O(n<sup>2</sup>) because there are a total of O(n<sup>2</sup>) substrings in a string, so if you have to generate them **all**, their number will be `n(n + 1) / 2` in the worst case, hence the <strike>upper</strike> lower bound of <strike>O(n<sup>2</sup>)</strike> Ω(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: We could hope for an output-sensitive algorithm that ran in O(# of unique strings)...

Comment: You mean a lower bound of Ω(n^2). :)

Comment: Suffix trees do it in O(n + L) time, where L is the number of unique substrings. For strings like 'aaaaa....aaaaa', L = O(n). So statement about Omega(n^2) is incorrect.

Comment: @Moron - I'm curious how suffix trees can solve this in O(n + L). Mind posting an algorithm?

Comment: @IVlad: Just walk the whole suffix tree and print the paths/sub-paths as you go along. Wouldn't that be O(L)? Of course this assumes that printing a string is O(1) (for instance, we print only the begin and end indices). If we consider printing string x to take O(|x|) time, then yes, it is Omega(n^2). That you have considered that is not clear from your post, and I would guess your post actually implies an Omega(n^3) lower bound for that case.

Comment: @IVlad: Of course, I haven't tried proving the claim about suffix trees, but it seems right to me. Also we can consider print=generate in above comment, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

First one is brute force which has complexity O(N^3) which could be brought down to    O(N^2 log(N))
 Second One using HashSet which has Complexity O(N^2)
 Third One using LCP by initially finding all the suffix of a given string which has the worst case O(N^2) and best case O(N Log(N)).

First Solution:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistinctSubString {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter The string");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int L = s.length();
    int N = L * (L + 1) / 2;
    String[] Comb = new String[N];
    for (int i = 0, p = 0; i < L; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < (L - i); ++j) {
        Comb[p++] = s.substring(j, i + j + 1);
      }
    }
    /*
     * for(int j=0;j<N;++j) { System.out.println(Comb[j]); }
     */
    boolean[] val = new boolean[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      val[i] = true;
    int counter = N;
    int p = 0, start = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j; i < L; ++i) {
      p = L - i;
      for (j = start; j < (start + p); ++j) {
        if (val[j]) {
          //System.out.println(Comb[j]);
          for (int k = j + 1; k < start + p; ++k) {
            if (Comb[j].equals(Comb[k])) {
              counter--;
              val[k] = false;
            }
          }
        }

      }

      start = j;
    }
    System.out.println("Substrings are " + N
        + " of which unique substrings are " + counter);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("It took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
  }
}
```

---

Second Solution:-

```
import java.util.*;

public class DistictSubstrings_usingHashTable {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // create a hash set

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter The string");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int L = s.length();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    // add elements to the hash set
    for (int i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < (L - i); ++j) {
        hs.add(s.substring(j, i + j + 1));
      }
    }
    System.out.println(hs.size());
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("It took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
  }
}
```

---

Third Solution:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LCPsolnFroDistinctSubString {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Desired String ");
    String string = br.readLine();
    int length = string.length();
    String[] arrayString = new String[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      arrayString[i] = string.substring(length - 1 - i, length);
    }

    Arrays.sort(arrayString);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
      System.out.println(arrayString[i]);

    long num_substring = arrayString[0].length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
      int j = 0;
      for (; j < arrayString[i].length(); ++j) {
        if (!((arrayString[i].substring(0, j + 1)).equals((arrayString)[i + 1]
            .substring(0, j + 1)))) {
          break;
        }
      }
      num_substring += arrayString[i + 1].length() - j;
    }
    System.out.println("unique substrings = " + num_substring);
  }

}
```

Fourth Solution:-

```
  public static void printAllCombinations(String soFar, String rest) {
    if(rest.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(soFar);
    } else {
        printAllCombinations(soFar + rest.substring(0,1), rest.substring(1));
        printAllCombinations(soFar , rest.substring(1));
    }
}

Test case:-  printAllCombinations("", "abcd");
```

Comment: How is the best case in third solution is O(nlogn)

Comment: Okay. You've counted all unique substrings. Great. But how would you "Generate all unique substrings for given string" with a suffix array/longest common prefix array?

Answer (score 3):

For big oh ... Best you could do would be O(n^2)

No need to reinvent the wheel, its not based on a strings, but on a sets, so you will have to take the concepts and apply them to your own situation.

Algorithms

[Really Good White Paper from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163513.aspx)

[In depth PowerPoint](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit594-2005/Lectures/05-simple-recursion.ppt)

[Blog on string perms](http://n1b-algo.blogspot.com/2009/01/string-permutations.html)

Comment: Err, what? O(a^n)? What is a and where did you pull that result from?

Comment: sorry that notation defines growth over time... i switched back

Comment: Using LCP(longest common suffix) the best time could be pulled down to O(NLog N)

Comment: @SumitKumarSaha You mean Longest Common **Prefix**.

Comment: @goelakash yes prefix, i am unable to edit my previous comment

Answer (score 2):

well, since there is potentially `n*(n+1)/2` different substrings (+1 for the empty substring), I doubt you can be better than `O(n*2)` (worst case). the easiest thing is to generate them and use some nice `O(1)` lookup table (such as a hashmap) for excluding duplicates right when you find them.

Comment: It's `n(n+1)/2`. "abc" has 3*4/2 = 6 substrings ("a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "abc") not 3*2/2 = 3 substrings.

Comment: Note that hash tables use hashcodes and equals which are O(n) for the length of the string.

Comment: oh, yes, sorry ... will fix that ... :)

Comment: @fgb using a rolling hash for example you can get O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 2):

```
class SubstringsOfAString {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String string = "Hello", sub = null;

        System.out.println("Substrings of \"" + string + "\" are :-");

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= string.length() - i; j++) {
                sub = string.substring(i, j + i);
                System.out.println(sub);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class program
{

        List<String> lst = new List<String>();
        String str = "abc";
        public void func()
        {

            subset(0, "");
            lst.Sort();
            lst = lst.Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (String item in lst)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
        void subset(int n, String s)
        {
            for (int i = n; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(s + str[i].ToString());
                subset(i + 1, s + str[i].ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This prints unique substrings.
https://ideone.com/QVWOh0

```
def uniq_substring(test):
    lista=[]
    [lista.append(test[i:i+k+1]) for i in range(len(test)) for k in
    range(len(test)-i) if test[i:i+k+1] not in lista and 
    test[i:i+k+1][::-1] not in lista]
    print lista

uniq_substring('rohit')
uniq_substring('abab')

['r', 'ro', 'roh', 'rohi', 'rohit', 'o', 'oh', 'ohi', 'ohit', 'h',   
'hi', 'hit', 'i', 'it', 't']
['a', 'ab', 'aba', 'abab', 'b', 'bab']
```

Answer (score 1):

Many answers that include 2 for loops and a .substring() call claim O(N^2) time complexity. However, it is important to note that the worst case for a .substring() call in Java (post update 6 in Java 7) is O(N). So by adding a .substring() call in your code, the order of N has increased by one.

Therefore, 2 for loops and a .substring() call within those loops equals an O(N^3) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be done in o(n^2) time as total number of unique substrings of a string would be n(n+1)/2.

Example:

string s = "abcd"

pass 0: (all the strings are of length 1)

a, b, c, d = 4 strings

pass 1: (all the strings are of length 2)

ab, bc, cd = 3 strings

pass 2: (all the strings are of length 3)

abc, bcd = 2 strings

pass 3: (all the strings are of length 4)

abcd = 1 strings

Using this analogy, we can write solution with o(n^2) time complexity and constant space complexity.

The source code is as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print(char arr[], int start, int end)
{
    int i;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void substrings(char arr[], int n)
{
    int pass,j,start,end;
    int no_of_strings = n-1;

    for(pass=0;pass<n;pass++)
    {
        start = 0;
        end = start+pass;
        for(j=no_of_strings;j>=0;j--)
        {
            print(arr,start, end);
            start++;
            end = start+pass;
        }
        no_of_strings--;
    }

}

int main()
{   
    char str[] = "abcd";
    substrings(str,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive algorithm takes O(n^3) time instead of O(n^2) time.
There are O(n^2) number of substrings.
And if you put O(n^2) number of substrings, for example, set, 
then set compares O(lgn) comparisons for each string to check if it alrady exists in the set or not.
Besides it takes O(n) time for string comparison.
Therefore, it takes O(n^3 lgn) time if you use set. and you can reduce it O(n^3) time if you use hashtable instead of set.

The point is it is string comparisons not number comparisons.

So one of the best algorithm let's say if you use suffix array and longest common prefix (LCP) algorithm, it reduces O(n^2) time for this problem.
Building a suffix array using O(n) time algorithm.
Time for LCP = O(n) time.
Since for each pair of strings in suffix array, do LCP so total time is O(n^2) time to find the **length** of distinct subtrings.

Besides if you want to **print** all distinct substrings, it takes O(n^2) time.

Comment: Sets backed by hash tables exist, so you're comment about O(log n) look up into a set isn't correct. Also, you only have to do string equality checks if there is a hash collision.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  using a suffix array and longest common prefix. It can also give you the total number of unique substrings. The code might give a stack overflow in visual studio but runs fine in Eclipse C++. That's because it returns vectors for functions. Haven't tested it against extremely long strings. Will do so and report back.

```
  // C++ program for building LCP array for given text
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 100000
int cum[MAX];


// Structure to store information of a suffix
struct suffix
{
    int index; // To store original index
    int rank[2]; // To store ranks and next rank pair
};

// A comparison function used by sort() to compare two suffixes
// Compares two pairs, returns 1 if first pair is smaller
int cmp(struct suffix a, struct suffix b)
{
    return (a.rank[0] == b.rank[0])? (a.rank[1] < b.rank[1] ?1: 0):
        (a.rank[0] < b.rank[0] ?1: 0);
}

// This is the main function that takes a string 'txt' of size n as an
// argument, builds and return the suffix array for the given string
vector<int> buildSuffixArray(string txt, int n)
{
    // A structure to store suffixes and their indexes
    struct suffix suffixes[n];

    // Store suffixes and their indexes in an array of structures.
    // The structure is needed to sort the suffixes alphabatically
    // and maintain their old indexes while sorting
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        suffixes[i].index = i;
        suffixes[i].rank[0] = txt[i] - 'a';
        suffixes[i].rank[1] = ((i+1) < n)? (txt[i + 1] - 'a'): -1;
    }

    // Sort the suffixes using the comparison function
    // defined above.
    sort(suffixes, suffixes+n, cmp);

    // At his point, all suffixes are sorted according to first
    // 2 characters. Let us sort suffixes according to first 4
    // characters, then first 8 and so on
    int ind[n]; // This array is needed to get the index in suffixes[]
    // from original index. This mapping is needed to get
    // next suffix.
    for (int k = 4; k < 2*n; k = k*2)
    {
        // Assigning rank and index values to first suffix
        int rank = 0;
        int prev_rank = suffixes[0].rank[0];
        suffixes[0].rank[0] = rank;
        ind[suffixes[0].index] = 0;

        // Assigning rank to suffixes
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            // If first rank and next ranks are same as that of previous
            // suffix in array, assign the same new rank to this suffix
            if (suffixes[i].rank[0] == prev_rank &&
                    suffixes[i].rank[1] == suffixes[i-1].rank[1])
            {
                prev_rank = suffixes[i].rank[0];
                suffixes[i].rank[0] = rank;
            }
            else // Otherwise increment rank and assign
            {
                prev_rank = suffixes[i].rank[0];
                suffixes[i].rank[0] = ++rank;
            }
            ind[suffixes[i].index] = i;
        }

        // Assign next rank to every suffix
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int nextindex = suffixes[i].index + k/2;
            suffixes[i].rank[1] = (nextindex < n)?
                                suffixes[ind[nextindex]].rank[0]: -1;
        }

        // Sort the suffixes according to first k characters
        sort(suffixes, suffixes+n, cmp);
    }

    // Store indexes of all sorted suffixes in the suffix array
    vector<int>suffixArr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        suffixArr.push_back(suffixes[i].index);

    // Return the suffix array
    return suffixArr;
}

/* To construct and return LCP */
vector<int> kasai(string txt, vector<int> suffixArr)
{
    int n = suffixArr.size();

    // To store LCP array
    vector<int> lcp(n, 0);

    // An auxiliary array to store inverse of suffix array
    // elements. For example if suffixArr[0] is 5, the
    // invSuff[5] would store 0. This is used to get next
    // suffix string from suffix array.
    vector<int> invSuff(n, 0);

    // Fill values in invSuff[]
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        invSuff[suffixArr[i]] = i;

    // Initialize length of previous LCP
    int k = 0;

    // Process all suffixes one by one starting from
    // first suffix in txt[]
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        /* If the current suffix is at n-1, then we don’t
        have next substring to consider. So lcp is not
        defined for this substring, we put zero. */
        if (invSuff[i] == n-1)
        {
            k = 0;
            continue;
        }

        /* j contains index of the next substring to
        be considered to compare with the present
        substring, i.e., next string in suffix array */
        int j = suffixArr[invSuff[i]+1];

        // Directly start matching from k'th index as
        // at-least k-1 characters will match
        while (i+k<n && j+k<n && txt[i+k]==txt[j+k])
            k++;

        lcp[invSuff[i]] = k; // lcp for the present suffix.

        // Deleting the starting character from the string.
        if (k>0)
            k--;
    }

    // return the constructed lcp array
    return lcp;
}

// Utility function to print an array
void printArr(vector<int>arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    //t = 1;

    while (t > 0)  {

        //string str = "banana";
        string str;

        cin >> str; // >> k;

        vector<int>suffixArr = buildSuffixArray(str, str.length());
        int n = suffixArr.size();

        cout << "Suffix Array : \n";
        printArr(suffixArr, n);

        vector<int>lcp = kasai(str, suffixArr);

        cout << "\nLCP Array : \n";
        printArr(lcp, n);

        // cum will hold number of substrings if that'a what you want (total = cum[n-1]
        cum[0] = n - suffixArr[0];

    //  vector <pair<int,int>> substrs[n];

        int count = 1;


        for (int i = 1; i <= n-suffixArr[0]; i++)  {
            //substrs[0].push_back({suffixArr[0],i});
            string sub_str = str.substr(suffixArr[0],i);
            cout << count << "  "  <<  sub_str << endl;
            count++;
        }

        for(int i = 1;i < n;i++)  {

            cum[i] = cum[i-1] + (n - suffixArr[i] - lcp[i - 1]);

            int end = n - suffixArr[i];
            int begin = lcp[i-1] + 1;
            int begin_suffix = suffixArr[i];

            for (int j = begin, k = 1; j <= end; j++, k++)  {

                //substrs[i].push_back({begin_suffix, lcp[i-1] + k});
        //      cout << "i push "  << i  << "   " << begin_suffix << " " << k << endl;
                string sub_str = str.substr(begin_suffix, lcp[i-1] +k);
                cout << count << "  "  <<  sub_str << endl;
                count++;

            }

        }

        /*int count = 1;

        cout << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

            for (auto it = substrs[i].begin(); it != substrs[i].end(); ++it )    {

                string sub_str = str.substr(it->first, it->second);
                cout << count << "  "  <<  sub_str << endl;
                count++;
            }

        }*/


        t--;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's a simpler algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


char txt[100000], *p[100000];
int m, n;

int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
    int rc = memcmp(*(char **)p, *(char **)q, m);
    return rc;
}
int main() {
    std::cin >> txt;
    int start_s = clock();


    n = strlen(txt);
    int k; int i;
    int count = 1;
    for (m = 1; m <= n; m++) {
        for (k = 0; k+m <= n; k++)
            p[k] = txt+k;
        qsort(p, k, sizeof(p[0]), &cmp);
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (i != 0 && cmp(&p[i-1], &p[i]) == 0){
                continue;
            }
            char cur_txt[100000];
            memcpy(cur_txt, p[i],m);
            cur_txt[m] = '\0';
            std::cout << count << "  "  << cur_txt << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << --count  << endl;

    int stop_s = clock();
    float run_time = (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    cout << endl << "distinct substrings  \t\tExecution time = " << run_time << " seconds" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Both algorithms listed a simply too slow for extremely long strings though. I tested the algorithms against a string of length over 47,000 and the algorithms took over 20 minutes to complete, with the first one taking 1200 seconds, and the second one taking 1360 seconds, and that's just counting the unique substrings without outputting to the terminal. So for probably strings of length up to 1000 you might get a working solution. Both solutions did compute the same total number of unique substrings though. I did test both algorithms against string lengths of 2000 and 10,000. The times were for the first algorithm: 0.33 s and 12 s; for the second algorithm it was 0.535 s and 20 s. So it looks like in general the first algorithm is faster.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code in Python. It generates all possible substrings of any given string.

```
def find_substring(str_in):
    substrs = []
    if len(str_in) <= 1:
        return [str_in]

    s1 = find_substring(str_in[:1])
    s2 = find_substring(str_in[1:])

    substrs.append(s1)
    substrs.append(s2)
    for s11 in s1:
        substrs.append(s11)            
        for s21 in s2:            
            substrs.append("%s%s" %(s11, s21))

    for s21 in s2:
        substrs.append(s21)

    return set(substrs)
```

If you pass str_ = "abcdef" to the function, it generates the following results:

a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde, abcdef, abcdf, abce, abcef, abcf, abd, abde, abdef, abdf, abe, abef, abf, ac, acd, acde, acdef, acdf, ace, acef, acf, ad, ade, adef, adf, ae, aef, af, b, bc, bcd, bcde, bcdef, bcdf, bce, bcef, bcf, bd, bde, bdef, bdf, be, bef, bf, c, cd, cde, cdef, cdf, ce, cef, cf, d, de, def, df, e, ef, f

Comment: not a solution, because it mix all letters to build all words possible with given letters. the question is about all possible substrings... "abcdf" is not a substring of "abcdef"