# Get all Subsets of String through Dynamic Programming - Programming Contest,Interview

Tags: c++, puzzle

I have a string lets say 123

I need Output as

1,2,3,12,23,13,123 .

I know this can be achieved using Dynamic programming . So I need help.

The Length of the input string is in the range 10 ^ 6 .

Variation of this question : My next problem is

I have to only print those subsets where digits are consecutive.So now my answer becomes

1,2,3,12,23,123 .  NOTE : 13 doesnt appear here as 1 and 3 are not consecutive in the input string "123".

If not Dynamic Programming any other solution is also OK . Just remember that length of input string is 10^6 , so solution should be O(length)

Comment: are you looking for an answer so that you can participate in that codechef competition? I really don't think you should participate if you can't find the solution yourself, that'd be unfair.

Comment: Pity that it has to be C++. In Haskell, the function which does what you describe is simply `tail . sortBy (comparing length) . subsequences`.

Comment: The number of substrings would be O(2^length) in the first case, and O(length^2) in the second, how do you expect a O(length) time ...

Comment: @phresnel The codechef competition is over. I just need help solving it now

Comment: @fefe O(length) can be got using dynamic programming..

Comment: @Zer0: Then another question arises: What have you tried already?

Comment: There's going to be an enormous amount of substrings. Are you sure you are supposed to list them all? (Wouldn't you have to "visit" them all to list them, so how's that dynamic programming?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate all unique substrings for given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Consider using [suffix arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) to build up the substrings. Using a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) can reduce the complexity of finding suffixes to `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach: Use two loops iterating over the string. The outer loop sets always the beginning of the substring within the string, the inner loop increments from this starting position until the end of the string. Now the only thing that is left, is to select the characters of the string using `string::operator[]` and print/store them or whatever you want to do.

Coding is up to you ;)

Comment: How will this work when there are 3 digits to be considered. 2 loops will only take care of 2 digits.

So in the above case 123 will not be done at all..

Comment: No, there is no loop for each digit. These loops are nested. One inner and one outer loop. It's more like a sliding window with variable size.

Comment: Hmm ok . I dint see the substring part.. Cool.. Ill think about it