# generate all possible unique substring of a string

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I need to get all the unique substring of a string. I have stored the string into a `trie` but I am not able to figure out how can i used the same to print all the unique substring
for example

string `aab` all unique substrings are `{"a", "aa", "aab", "ab", "b"}`

here is my code for `trie`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

struct trie_node_t {
    typedef std::map<char, trie_node_t *> child_node_t;
    child_node_t m_childMap;
    trie_node_t() :m_childMap(std::map<char, trie_node_t*>()) {}

    void insert( std::string& word ) {
        trie_node_t *pNode = this;
        for ( std::string::const_iterator itr = word.begin(); itr != word.end(); ++itr) {
            char letter = *itr;
            if ( pNode->m_childMap.find(letter) == pNode->m_childMap.end()){
                pNode->m_childMap[letter] = new trie_node_t();
            }
            pNode = pNode->m_childMap[letter];
        }
    }

    void print() {
    }
};

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    trie_node_t trie;
    trie.insert(std::string("aab"));
    trie.print();
}
```

How do i implement `print` function which will print all the unique substring.

I am looking for `Linear time approach`

Since I have built a `trie`, is there a any way I can iterate over and whenever I visit any node I can print it as a unique string.

Comment: there is a memory leak in your code.  probably doesnt matter in *this* case but ...

Comment: strictly speaking, the empty-string is also considered a substring of all strings.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: But then again, he needs to print it, and every program prints the empty string :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262 . Suffix tree is the structure best suited to represent all unique substrings. You can build it in linear time even though there might be Theta(n^2) unique substrings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate all unique substrings for given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string)

Comment: @Rafał Dowgird, Suffix tree does not give me all the substring. http://ideone.com/AjZol , for aab i expect following string to come {"a", "aa", "aab", "ab", "b"}

Comment: @Avinash: I'll elaborate in a proper answer.

Comment: RafałDowgird Suffix tree is not essential. @Avinash, if you have already built the trie properly, all you have to do is navigate it once. Keep track of parent string and whenever you move to a child node append that letter and print it the string until that letter.

Comment: @ElKamina, I did built trie properly, but I did not get how to keep track of parent string, I will give another try, if you have any code sample, pls share.

Comment: func(node,str,n) { for (i = each_child_letter){str[n]=i;str[n+1]='\0'; func( node->child(i, str, n+1); }           Something like this. Call this with func(root_node, some_string, 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, build a suffix tree. This represents all suffixes of the string and can be done in linear time. Since every substring is a prefix of a suffix, now you need to enumerate the prefixes of the suffixes.

Fortunately if two suffixes share a common prefix, the prefix will be on a single common path from root, so there's a 1-1 mapping between paths from root(*) in the tree and unique suffixes.

Therefore it is sufficient to iterate over all paths from root in the suffix tree to produce all the unique substrings.

(*) The paths in the suffix tree are compressed, i.e. an edge might represent several characters. You need to uncompress the paths to produce all the substrings, i.e. treat compressed edges as multi-node paths.

Answer (score 0):

Note that every substring of `myString` has a length between `0` and `strlen(myString)`.  So just loop over every possible length, and every possible starting-position of the substring.

Comment: It will get all substrings, not all *unique* substrings. To get these he'll need to store a set of the existing strings, and the fastest way to do this  [in terms of big O notation]  is.... trie!

Comment: @amit: Ah, alright - I'll remove that part of the answer then.

Comment: I am looking for linear time approach

Comment: @Avinash: You will not get linear time. concider the string "abcd..." there are O(n^2) substrings. generating them will be `O(n^2)`, no matter what you do.

Comment: @Avinash:  Linear in, what, the length of the input string?  The number of substrings is quadratic, so what you are asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There are "end signs" in `Trie`, i.e. if a node is the last char of a string, then it's marked as one `terminal`.

So if you need to print all the strings in a `Trie`, you'll need to `dfs()` on that `Trie`, whenever visiting a node with `end sign`(which means it's a terminal), you know it's the last char of some string, so print it.