# Can I generate all substrings in complexity < O(n^2)

Tags: java, suffix-tree, substring

Currently I am using two nested `for` loop to generate all the substrings of a string. I heard about `Suffix Tree` but AFAIK `Suffix Tree` generates suffix not the substrings. Following is the code which currently i am using-

```
        String s = "abacbccca";
        int l = s.length();
        for (short c = 0; c < l; c++) {
            for (short r = 0; r < l - c; r++){
                Sting ss=s.substring(c, c + r + 1);                                        
                if(!t.contains(ss));
                    t.add(ss);
            }
        }
```

I want a way which can generate all the substrings in less than `O(n^2)`. Although by seeing my code, anyone can suggest me that it's impossible, as i am adding every substring to a list. But my objective is not to store all the substrings, my objective is to find a string which is lexicographically ith smallest string.

Comment: If you are interested in the lexicographically smallest string only, then I am afraid Niklas B. below is right. But if you are interested in a O(n)-size data structure that allows you to access the i-th smallest string for any given i, as your question seems to suggest, then perhaps my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9389681/777186) helps.

Comment: @jogojapan: Yeah.... that what i want... Thank you so so so much...

Answer (score 14):

There *are* `O(n^2)` different substrings, so no algorithm can enumerate them all with a complexity better than `O(n^2)`!

The problem of finding the lexicographically smallest substring is a totally different one, though. It's always the empty string, so that's an `O(1)` operation (and a very pointless one, too).

Comment: Okay.... Can you please elaborate more about finding `lexicographically` smallest substring?

Comment: @Ravi: Typically, when lexicographically comparing strings, [if one of the strings is a prefix of the other, it's considered smaller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Ordering_of_sequences_of_various_lengths). So the smallest substring is always the empty string: `String smallestSubstring(String x) { return ""; }` By the way, I wrote that in my answer as well.

Comment: If `null` is not allowed, then??? .. Let say we have string abacba, it has these unique substrings `{a,ab,aba,abac,abacb,abacba,b,ba,bac,bacb,bacba,ac,acb,acba,c,cb,cba}` . Now lexicographically smallest string is the above set is `a`.

Comment: @Ravi: No, it also has the substring `""` (empty string, has nothing to do with `null`!), which is the smallest. If you exclude the empty string (which wouldn't be consequent), then the smallest substring is always the smallest substring of length 1.

Comment: But i am saying about the `lexicographically smallest substring`. In the above example, we have three smallest substrings of length 1, which are `a`,`b` and `c`. But lexicographically smallest substring is `a` not `b` or `c`.

Comment: @Ravi: I can only repeat myself: "the smallest substring is always the smallest substring of length 1". In this case, `{a,b,c}` are the substrings of length 1 and `a` is the smallest of them. Sorry, but you seem to be a bit confused about this. What are you trying to achieve? I don't see any real world usage of this.

Comment: @NiklasB. Sorry, Niklas but I found your answer quite funny! Thanks for the chuckle.