# Udi Manber and Gene Myers Method

Tags: algorithm, suffix-array

I have a suffix array SA, and an array L that stores the length of [LCP](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs548/references/linear_lcp.pdf) (longest common prefix) between two consecutive suffixes, i.e.

```
L[i]=LCP(SA[i-1],SA[i]) where 1<=i<=|SA|
```

It's also described [here](http://pps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=RevisionHistory&messageID=1171511).

How should I use this array L to find the LCP(x,y) between given two suffixes x and y?

Comment: @ High Performance Mark:: I have edited it.Actually this was the exact question that i asked  2-3 days before ,but as i did n't get any response , so made the problem easier and straight forward .

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but is (2) answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9390461/777186) perhaps? If yes, we could consider (2) done and concentrate on (1).

Comment: @jogojapan:: Yup 2 is answered .Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complete Suffix Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389681/complete-suffix-array)

Comment: @jogojapan::I have edited my question. [I removed my second question,as it is answered].

Comment: Great, it's much clearer now. About the remaining question: Do you really need LCP(x,y) for *any* values of x and y? If you want to use this to implement binary search across the suffix array (and I think that is what you mean by 'Manber/Myers method'), you only need a certain subset of the possible values of x and y. If that is what you are interested in, I can provide an answer.

Comment: Yeah ,can you plz provide answer. LCP b/w any values of x and y is what i want.

Comment: If you do need LCP for *any* x,y (**not** only the subset relevant for the Manber/Myers suffix array search algorithm), then the answer is quite complicated. The basic idea is that you use the standard LCP that you have already, and then for given x,y you look at all values LCP[x+1],...,LCP[y] and find the minimum. The minimum is the LCP of x and y that you want. In other words, you need to compute an RMQ (range minimum query) on your existing LCP array. The naive method takes O(n). But there are O(1)-time, O(n)-space methods. E.g.  described by Sadakane, DOI: 10.1007/s00224-006-1198-x.

Comment: @ jogojapan :Thanks a lot,i got the solution.yes ,its RMQ .If i had standard Lcp calculate then i just have to find the RMQ. And it can be done in O(nlogn) preprocessing and O(1) query time .Thanks indeed!

Comment: @jogojapan Your comment is pretty much the answer that should be posted here. Can you convert that into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
rank[0...7]: 4 6 8 1 2 3 5 7 
string:      a a b a a a a b 
------------------------------------------- 
 sa[1] = 3 : a a a a b         height[1] = 0 
 sa[2] = 4 : a a a b           height[2] = 3 
 sa[3] = 5 : a a b             height[3] = 2 
 sa[4] = 0 : a a b a a a a b   height[4] = 3 
 sa[5] = 6 : a b               height[5] = 1 
 sa[6] = 1 : a b a a a a b     height[6] = 2 
 sa[7] = 7 : b                 height[7] = 0 
 sa[8] = 2 : b a a a a b       height[8] = 1
```

Here array **height** is equal to array **L**

using array **sa** , we can easily calculate array **rank**

Then using **Sparse Table (ST) algorithm** to calculate **rmq question**.
http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Range_Minimum_Query_%28RMQ%29

```
int *RMQ = height;
//int RMQ[N];
int mm[N];
int best[20][N]; //best[i][j] means the minimal value in the range [j, j + 2^i)
void initRMQ(int n){
  int i,j,a,b;
  for(mm[0]=-1,i=1;i<=n;i++)
  mm[i]=((i&(i-1))==0)?mm[i-1]+1:mm[i-1];
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) best[0][i]=i;
  for(i=1;i<=mm[n];i++)
  for(j=1;j<=n+1-(1<<i);j++){
    a=best[i-1][j];
    b=best[i-1][j+(1<<(i-1))];
    if(RMQ[a]<RMQ[b]) best[i][j]=a;
    else best[i][j]=b;
  }
}
int askRMQ(int a,int b){
  int t;
  t=mm[b-a+1];b-=(1<<t)-1;
  a=best[t][a];b=best[t][b];
  return RMQ[a]<RMQ[b]?a:b;
}
int lcp(int a,int b){ //this is your answer
  int t;
  a=rank[a];b=rank[b];
  if(a>b) {t=a;a=b;b=t;}
  return(height[askRMQ(a+1,b)]);
}
```

Then just call the function lcp(). Time and space is O(nlogn)