# Algorithm help is needed (Codility)

Tags: c++, algorithm

In this problem we consider only strings consisting of lower-case English letters (a−z).
A string is a palindrome if it reads exactly the same from left to right as it does from right to left.

For example, these strings are palindromes:

```
aza
abba
abacaba
```

These strings are not palindromes:

```
zaza
abcd
abacada
```

Given a string S of length N, a slice of S is a substring of S specified by a pair of integers (p, q), such that `0 ≤ p < q < N`. A slice (p, q) of string S is palindromic if the string consisting of letters `S[p], S[p+1], ..., S[q]` is a palindrome.

For example, in a string `S = abbacada:`

slice (0, 3) is palindromic because `abba` is a palindrome,
slice (6, 7) is not palindromic because `da` is not a palindrome,
slice (2, 5) is not palindromic because `baca` is not a palindrome,
slice (1, 2) is palindromic because `bb` is a palindrome.

---

Write a function `int solution(const string &S);` that, given a string S of length N letters, returns the number of palindromic slices of S. The function should return −1 if this number is greater than 100,000,000.

For example, for string `S = baababa` the function should return 6, because exactly six of its slices are palindromic; namely: `(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 6)`.

Assume that:
- N is an integer within the range [0..20,000];
- string S consists only of lower-case letters (a−z).

Complexity:
- expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
- expected worst-case space complexity is O(N) (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

Here is my solution:

```
int palindrom(const string &S, int startIndex,int endIndex, int counter=0)
{ 
    bool equals = true;
    if (endIndex - startIndex < 1)
        return counter;
    for(int i = startIndex,j = endIndex;i<j; ++i, --j)
    {
        equals = S[i] == S[j];
        if (!equals) break;
    }
    if (equals) counter++;
    counter = palindrom( S,startIndex,endIndex-1,counter);
    return counter;
}

int solution(const string &S)
{
    int length = S.size();
    int counter = 0;
    if (length > 20000) return -1;
    for(int i=0; i < length-1; i++)
    {
        counter += palindrom(S,i,length-1);
        if (counter > 100000000) return -1;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

with big strings S.size()>3000 I always get runtime error(means time is more then 3 sec but solution should work in less then 2 seconds)! Any suggestions?

ok! and main function is something like:

```
main(){cout<<solution("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");}
```

Comment: Format your code so we can read it without scrolling.   Include the error so we can make an informed guess.    What platform are you running on?   What compiler are you using?

Comment: Don't miss the [Formatting Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), it's badly needed on a question like this. People will be more willing to do work for you if you make it easy on them.

Comment: The down votes are pointless.   Give him a chance to improve the question.   This looks like an interesting one.

Comment: I would do it - but can't :(. It doesn't submit my question (((. Can Anybody do it for me, please.

Comment: @devworkstation You have to use the [edit] link, you can't submit a new question that is exactly the same as this one. Otherwise I'm not sure what problems you're running into. Jrok already formatted the big code block, but you should be able to add line breaks to create paragraphs and surround inline code blocks with backticks (``)

Comment: Can you post `main()` and your input text?

Comment: The main function is missing.  Please add that.   I see 20K and 100M constants in the solution function.  Why those values?

Comment: I really afraid to do Editing staff :)

Comment: Well then, I'm afraid to look at the problem any more.

Comment: @devworkstation you're using a massive recursion depth, try to increase your stack size. Look up how to do it with your compiler and/or your OS.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT! I just updated the question - it works in more then 3 seconds but should be done in 2 seconds. It is a test task from Codility - so no access to compiler or OS :)

Comment: You need double quotes for the function argument.

Comment: How does this even work? You do `counter++` and afterwards `counter = ...`. Does this mean you pass counter by reference? Please fix your edit then

Comment: @tohava that part is fine, it may just confuse you that he passes the value of counter on the rhs before overwriting counter on the lhs with the return value.

Comment: Quick question, are you looking for all palindromic substrings of `S` or all substrings starting at each index in `S`. eg with `S = "ababa"`, would `{[0, 2], [0, 4], [2, 4], [1, 3]}` be the solution set?

Comment: @ErikNguyen the second variant (all substrings starting at each index in S)

Comment: @Blastfurnace..... hm... looks like it is possible to do in O(n) with Manacher’s algorithm.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do without recursion

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::string::const_iterator P;

bool is_palindrom(P begin, P end) {
    while (begin < end) {
        if (*begin != *end)
            return false;
        ++begin;
        --end;
    }
    return true;
}

int count_palindroms(const std::string &s) {
    int c = 0;
    P left = s.begin();
    while (left < s.end()) {
        P right = left + 1; // because length palindrome > 1
        while (right < s.end()) {
            if (is_palindrom(left, right)) {
                //std::cout << left - s.begin() << ' ' << right - s.begin() << std::endl;
                c++;
                if (c > 100000000)
                    return -1;
            }
            ++right;
        }
        ++left;
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int , char *[])
{
    std::cout << count_palindroms("baababa") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
As for me - my solution looks more readable. But anyway your solution is still very slow.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on my PC.
What you are actually doing here is checking every sub string of the original string and run a recursive function over it.
As @PeterT mentioned you probably reach the max depth of your stuck.

What I would do is not use the call stack, but either use my own stuck, or use some simple string functions like:

```
std::string s = "aba";
std::string s1 = std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()); 
if (s == s1)
{
///...
}
```

for an example.

Regarding the time complexity - as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string) you can't check them all in o(n).

Comment: He does not want to print all strings, only to count them. This might invalidate the proof of `O(n^2)`. Although admittedly, I also think this can't be done in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply delete the recursion (with a small change in the algorithm):

```
int palindrom(const string &S, int startIndex, int endIndex, int counter = 0)
{
    for (int k = endIndex; k > startIndex; --k) {
        bool equals = true;
        for (int i = startIndex, j = k; i < j; ++i, --j)
            if (S[i] != S[j]) {
                equals = false;
                break;
            }
        if (equals)
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```