# Substrings of a string without nested loops

Tags: java, string, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I need to do some complex work on all substrings of the given string, for which I need to find all substrings of the given string. I am wondering if it is possible to do without nested loops (n^2 complexity)?

Any other suggestions on optimizing this?

```
int originalStringlength = str.length();
for(int start = 0 ; start < originalStringlength ; start++){
   for(int chars = 1; chars <= originalStringlength - start; chars++){
      String substr = str.substring(start, start+chars);
      System.out.prinln("Substring: " +  substr);
    //do further processing
   }    
}
```

Comment: Surely there are `O(n^2)` substrings though, meaning that you need an `O(n^2)` algorithm if you want to print them all?

Comment: It is the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string

Comment: You could  replace a for with a while! :)

Comment: Right! Thanks for pointing out - my search didn't show that! :(