# Pairs with no duplicates grouped together

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have a table

```
ID  GROUPID  NAME
==  =======  ========
 1      100  A
 2      100  B
 3      200  C
 4      200  D
 5      300  E
 6      100  F
```

I would like to create a table containing the permutation pairs within a group without any pairs that are the same on both first and second that looks like this:

```
 PAIRID  FIRST  SECOND
 ======  =====  ======
      1      1       2
      2      1       6
      3      2       1
      4      2       6
      5      3       4
      6      4       3
      7      6       1
      8      6       2
```

I would like to do it in PL/SQL or straight SQL inserts if possible.  I did this [through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323560/242042) already using a recursive function to go through the permutations.

Comment: OK, so the column NAME plays no role, correct?

Comment: Correct it is there so I can call it "a", "b", "c" if there are any discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could self join the table:

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.id, b.id) AS pairid, 
         a.id AS FIRST, b.id AS second
FROM     mytable a
JOIN     mytable b ON a.groupid = b.groupid AND a.id <> b.id
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Comment: Almost there, but - while the OP did not say it explicitly - it looks like the pairid is assigned based on "ORDER BY first, second". So a `ROW_NUMBER()` seems necessary.