# How to delete substrings with space in all possible substrings of a string?

Tags: c++

The question is to find all possible substrings  in a given string.

I know this question is somewhat similar to this.

[Generate all unique substrings for given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string)

But i'm trying it on my own. I have generated all possible combinations but problem is i want to eliminate some strings with space in them.

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t>0){
        long long int n;
        cin>>n;
        string S;
        cin>>S;
        for(int i=1; i<=S.size(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<=S.size()-1; j++) {

                cout<<S.substr(j,i)<<endl;
            }
        }

        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
1
3
abb
```

Actual output:

```
a
b
b
ab
bb
b
abb
bb
b
```

Expected output:

```
a
b
b
ab
bb
abb
```

As you can see there are some terms with space in them which i want to eliminate like 6th,8th and 9th terms in Actual output.

Comment: Hint: for a string of length 3, `S.substr(1,2)` and `S.substr(1,3)`, and in fact also `S.substr(1, 1000)` all produce the same substring.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `std::string::substr`

The substring is the portion of the object that starts at character position pos and **spans len characters** (or until the end of the string, whichever comes first).

You are under the misconception that the second argument of `std::string::substr` is the end position, but in fact it is an offset from the first argument.