# Find all substring in a string in Python, how can I make it better?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, substring

how can I make it better? is there any algorithm/method to make it better and shorter?

```
def sub_string_finder(string):
    given_string = string.upper()
    substring_of = []
    length = len(given_string)
    # find all substring and put it in substring array
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i + 1, length + 1):
            substring_of.append(given_string[i:j])
    return substring_of


s = input("Enter a string: ")
print(f"Number of substring: {len(sub_string_finder(s))}")
print(sub_string_finder(s))
```

Output for "developer":

```
Number of substring: 45
['D', 'DE', 'DEV', 'DEVE', 'DEVEL', 'DEVELO', 'DEVELOP', 'DEVELOPE', 'DEVELOPER', 'E', 'EV', 'EVE', 'EVEL', 'EVELO', 'EVELOP', 'EVELOPE', 'EVELOPER', 'V', 'VE', 'VEL', 'VELO', 'VELOP', 'VELOPE', 'VELOPER', 'E', 'EL', 'ELO', 'ELOP', 'ELOPE', 'ELOPER', 'L', 'LO', 'LOP', 'LOPE', 'LOPER', 'O', 'OP', 'OPE', 'OPER', 'P', 'PE', 'PER', 'E', 'ER', 'R']
```

`Update`

This is the final answer until now using `itertools` and `combinations`, Thanks to the respondents. To increase readability we can use line break. Remember that [Python allows line breaks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining) between brackets and braces.

```
from itertools import combinations


def sub_string_finder(string):
    substring_of = [
    string.upper()[i:j] 
    for i, j in combinations(range(len(string) + 1), r=2)
]
    return substring_of
```

If you are interested in learning about Python List Comprehensions, you can chek [this](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

Comment: As for alghorithm itself you might read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string though note that is about bit different task (finding all *unique* substrings of string)

Comment: What should be the output for input `aaaa`?

Comment: input == "aaaa", output == ['A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AAAA', 'A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'A', 'AA', 'A']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the nested loop as one line. You can also skip the check `!= ""` if you start the second inner from `i + 1`

```
def sub_string_finder(string):
    given_string = string.upper()
    length = len(given_string)
    substring_of = [given_string[i:j] for i in range(length) for j in range(i + 1, length + 1)]

    return substring_of
```

Or using `combinations` from `itertools`

```
substring_of = [given_string[i:j] for i, j in combinations(range(len(given_string) + 1), r=2) if given_string[i:j] != ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit shorter, based on the @Guy suggestion (without itertools):

```
def sub_string_finder(string):
    substring_of = [string.upper()[i:j] for i in range(len(string)) for j in range(i + 1, len(string) + 1)]
    return substring_of
```